# What capacitor and resistor to use in my simple circuit?

Tags: resistors, motor

I’m quite new to electronics but I’m making progress learning about it. I would like to make a circuit to control the speed of two electromotors. (Or two circuits to control separately, whatever is most practical). I got the electromotors from a blender and a drilling machine both labels say: 230V 50 Hz.

I looked at the blender as an example. It seems to be a condenser (6nF, X2 275V?), a resistor 1Mohm and the motor (400w) all in parallel. I know that a condenser is often used for a motor to start turning. How do you know/can I calculate what the value of the condenser should be? And for the resistor, why would they put a 1Mohm one in parallel with the motor and condenser?

Eventually I would like to control the speed in some way. Stepwise or more smooth. Do you have any ideas for this?

Thanks!

Comment: *"I’m quite new to electronics" ... "both labels say: 230V 50 Hz."...* There's that queasy feeling in the pit of my stomach again... I would suggest doing your learning at low voltages (12V, DC, say) instead of messing with mains, until you have built up a good grounding in the basics.

Comment: @Majenko: Indeed. Without knowing the basics, a good grounding while messing with mains can be fatal.

Comment: 6nf has nothing to do with controlling rotation. 1 microfarad or 6 microfarads, maybe. I'm guessing that motor has brushes, yes? Then it's for noise suppression.

Answer (score 1):

The motors used in those kinds of appliances are typically "universal" motors, which are basically series-connected (armature and stator) via a set of brushes.

The capacitor is there to help keep the electrical switching noise of the brushes from feeding back to the line cord and radiating into any nearby AM radios. It may or may not be effective at this.

The resistor is there to discharge the capacitor. Under some circumstances, the brushes on the motor might stop in an "open circuit" condition, and if the power switch is opened near a peak of the AC waveform, a significant charge can be left on the the capacitor. This could become a danger if the appliance is subsequently unplugged and someone touches the prongs of the plug. So the resistor bleeds off this residual charge in a reasonable amount of time (a few seconds at most).

Answer (score 0):

To control the speed of this AC motor you could use an AC motor controller module.

Take a look at this one for example:
http://electronics-diy.com/1000w-ac-motor-speed-controller.php